# jQuery mouseenter works great with mouse but not with tab key

Tags: jquery

```
$( "#list li:eq(0)" ).bind('mouseenter focus', function(event) {

jQuery("#logo img").css('top', '-132px');
console.log( event.type, " :: ", this.id );
  }).bind('blur mouseleave', function(event) {

jQuery("#logo img").css('top', '-41px');
console.log( event.type, " :: ", this.id );
  });
```

This piece of jQuery works great with the mouse over but not with the tab key over!
Have you encounter a similar problem?

I have tried .bind to fire both event and still not working!

**if fires the event on mouseenter but nothing in focus!**

Comment: Are you surprised that **mouse** enter does not trigger when you do things on the **keyboard**?

Comment: why is it that you are using a combonation of `$` and `jQuery`?

Comment: Use `focus` and `blur` or `focusout` instead. I think those are able to handle keyboard and mouse events alltogether.

Comment: Use CSS Classes... not individual styles.

Comment: No seriously use a class, I'm shuddering here and grinding my teeth just looking at how ugly that code is because you need to do `.css(123).css(456).css(789)` instead of `.addClasS("foo")`

Comment: seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/atoswchataigner/Yveuj/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` have nothing to do with keyboard events, and are not fired when an element gains keyboard `focus`.

To have your code fire on both `mouseenter` and `focus`, this is a bit closer:

```
$("#MesActivites li:eq(0)").bind("mouseenter focus", function (event) {
    jQuery("#MesActivites ul:eq(1)").css('top', '45px').css('left', '-1px');
    jQuery("#rfr-header-logo").css('display', 'none');
    console.log(event.type, " :: ", this.id);
}).bind("mouseleave blur", function (event) {
    jQuery("#MesActivites ul:eq(1)").css('top', '-1000px').css('left', '-1px');
    jQuery("#rfr-header-logo").css('display', 'block');
    console.log(event.type, " :: ", this.id);
});
```

Comment: @xgrioux this answer is 6 years old and the `bind()` event that it uses is deprecated, for it to work you may need jQuery migrate. Alternatively use the newer `off()` and `on()` event binding functions. More here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks @jammypeach

Comment: So should it be: "...).on('mouseenter focus',..."

Answer (score 2):

Mouse events don't generally fire for key presses.  `.focus()` and `.blur()` are what you're after.

- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Edit: most non-form elements cannot accept focus by default, you need to add a `tabindex` attribute to them:

```
<li tabindex="0" ... > ... </li>
```

Comment: And in order to avoid duplicating code, use `.bind('mouseenter focus', function(){...})` and so on.

Comment: @user: have you added the `tabindex` attribute to your element?