# event can be only triggered by mouse, without any impact on Tab clicking

Tags: jquery, accessibility

I have the following code. However, the event is triggered when both mouse entering selector and selector is given focus via <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```
$("selector").mouseenter(function(){

     $(this).addClass("red");

})
```

I would like to an event can be only triggered by mouse, without being able to <kbd>Tab</kbd> to it.

Comment: You can ignore it from tabindex if that helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192859/html-remove-element-from-tab-index

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this and give more code? `mouseEnter()` only fires when you use the mouse, not the Tab, per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916754/jquery-mouseenter-works-great-with-mouse-but-not-with-tab-key), so you are firing it on something like an anchor or has a `tabindex="0"`. People who follow this tag often work for make the web more accessible, so this may be seen as the opposite.